# "il est" when it means "il y a"

Tags: sens, usage, histoire

In some works of literature, I see "il est" used to mean "il y a". For instance, in Figaro's famous line "il n'est point d'éloge flatteur". In a televised adaptation of Molière's "The Imaginary Invalid", the protagonist says "parce qu'il est en lui une vertu dormitive ..."

Do people continue to use "il est" in this way? Or has this sense of the phrase faded away?

Comment: I don't know why the answers are vague about this, but no. No one says that nowadays.

Comment: @TeleportingGoat I agree (almost) no one says that in normal conversation but the phrase is still alive in written French.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Do people continue to use "il est" in this way? Or has this sense of the phrase faded away?

While you shouldn't expect to hear it in casual conversation, the sense of this phrase has not faded away. It still appears either in very formal speaking or in written French. e.g.:

> ***Il n'est pas de jour** où je ne me connecte sur Internet.*

---

> ***Il est des choses** qu'une mère ne peut raconter à son fils.* *Olivier Deck, Le chant des passereaux, 2012*
>
> *Diacre, **il est des choses** qui ne sont pas de ton ressort. N'y aventure pas ton grand nez.* *Cavanna, Le sang de clovis, 2001*
>
> ***Il est des jours** où on voudrait avoir eu tort d'avoir prédit, avec beaucoup d'autres, que les désordres écologiques, financiers, politiques et culturels finiraient par ne plus être des hypothèses* *Jacques Attali, Perspectives économiques, 2012*
>
> *Je me souviens que quelques jours après cette déclaration en forme d’aveu, la Société des Compositeurs et Auteurs déclarait : « (…) **s’il est des excuses à présenter**, je crois que c’est plutôt TF1 qui devrait les présenter à la France. »* [plumedepresse.net](http://www.plumedepresse.net/renaud-revel-tf1-a-droite-cest-absurde/)

---

While very close, there is a slight difference between *il est* and *il y a*. The former must introduce something generic while the latter can also introduce something specific, e.g.:

> ***Il est** des gens qui se contentent de peu.* Generic; a self sufficient, indefinite and impersonal statement. (People who content themselves with not a lot exist)
>
> ***Il y a** des gens qui se contentent de peu.* Specific; personal; some examples might follow. (There are people who are contenting themselves with not a lot).

That means ***il est*** cannot always replace ***il y a***. Another example: ***il y a un homme** qui vous attend* (there is a man [here] who is waiting for you) is noticeably different than ***il est un homme** qui vous attend* (some man is waiting for you somewhere.)

However, in classical literature and poetry, *il **y a*** was very often avoided and replaced by *il est* simply to avoid the hiatus, here 'y' followed by 'a' in two different syllables.

Référence: Grammaire des grammaires, Girault-Divivier, 1840, [p1167](https://books.google.fr/books?id=W9ISAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA1167&lpg=PA1167&dq=%22il%20est%20des%22%20%22il%20y%20a%20des%22%20grammaire&source=bl&ots=Do7H2CHpfh&sig=-BxK1lrSoHzcO4O7cS1-gfN1kEU&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjCg9a36-jRAhVKSRoKHRKsDkkQ6AEIHTAA#v=onepage&q&f=false).

Avoiding that hiatus is also probably a reason why this phrase is still often used in newspapers, for example [an article in today's L'Obs](http://tempsreel.nouvelobs.com/presidentielle-2017/20170129.OBS4519/francois-fillon-les-yeux-humides-on-ne-m-intimidera-pas.html) starts with:

> ***Il est** des meetings qui comptent. Pour François Fillon, celui de dimanche est de ceux-là.*

Comment: the difference feels _slight_ indeed :-)

Comment: I'm continuing to think about this proposed slight difference, and it might exist, maybe because "_il est_" refers to unqualified existence, whereas "_il y a_" seems to be an introduction to more details, but don't think it is a very strict rule.

Comment: @Frank Obviously not a strict rule but I found a reference about it here [grammaire des grammaires, Girault-Duvivier, page 1167](https://books.google.fr/books?id=W9ISAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA1167&lpg=PA1167&dq=%22il+est+des%22+%22il+y+a+des%22+grammaire&source=bl&ots=Do7H2CHpfh&sig=-BxK1lrSoHzcO4O7cS1-gfN1kEU&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjCg9a36-jRAhVKSRoKHRKsDkkQ6AEIHTAA#v=onepage&q&f=false)

Comment: nice - I tried to check the Grevisse, but didn't find anything there.

Comment: Nota bene: La grammaire des grammaires date de 1840.

Comment: @Frank Oui, je l'ai bien sûr vu. La nuance qu'elle décrit et les exemples donnés où « il est » ne peut se substituer à « il y a » me semblent toujours pertinents. On ne peut pas écrire aujourd'hui, même dans un style littéraire, « il est du beurre dans les épinards ».

Comment: il serait peut-être intéressant de mentionner plus d'exemples de cette grammaire des grammaires?

Comment: Merci @giliagre, la réponse est fort utile!

Comment: @Frank The difference between the use of "il y a" and "il est" is more subtle than "slight difference" ... (see below)

Comment: @sapienz There is a slight difference in meaning and an obvious and strong difference in level of formality and usage.

Comment: @giliagre I agree.

Answer (score 1):

In the context of your question ***"Il y a"*** and ***"il est"*** present the same meaning in the stylistic sens.

However, the first belongs to the current language while the second appears to belong to more refined language

Comment: But see jlliagre's answer: actually still used in writing sometimes.

Comment: The difference between the use of "il y a" and "il est" is more subtle than "slight difference". 
It marks the level of language style. Of course the use of "il est" in: "il est des jours ou je ne veux pas aller au travail" is somewhat ...weak. 
In Baudelaire's Les Fleurs du mal, one can find: "il est des parfums frais comme des chairs d'enfants".

Comment: Yes, I remembered that line from Baudelaire instantly when I saw "il est" :-)

Answer (score 1):

In a sense, you could make a case that *il est* is more logical than *il y a*: *il est en lui une vertu dormitive*, for exemple, refers to the **existence** of a *vertu*, and *existence* would naturally involve the verb *être* rather than the verb *avoir*. But usage ended up favoring *il y a* over *il est*, and *il est* is not used when speaking anymore. Even in writing, it sounds quite formal.