# Translation of "Although still very young ..."

Tags: adjectifs, subordonnées

> Although still very young, he is already a very good lawyer.

How can we translate this sentence?

> Même si encore très jeune, il est déjà un très bon avocat.

I'm not sure if "il est déjà un très bon avocat" is correct, because normally we would have to use "**c'est** un très bon avocat". But saying

> Même si encore très jeune, c'est déjà un très bon avocat.

doesn't seem correct either.

Comment: The Académie Française doesn't like *"il est un"*: http://www.academie-francaise.fr/il-est-cest-un-0

Comment: @SimonDéchamps - I am not sure this applies here. There are other words between "un" and "avocat". I have found multiple instances of "il est un très <adjective> <noun>", including in authors such as Voltaire. For example: "car on me dit qu'outre ses talens, **il est un très honnête homme**.", "car **il est un très-bon homme de main**", "... iui a restitué les justices de Saint-Pierre, et qu'**il est un très-excellent prince**..." ...

Comment: I believe the context is important, and the example from the Académie Française is not quite the same as what is written here, IMHO.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Although still very young, he is already a very good lawyer.

might be translated by:

> *Bien qu'il soit encore très jeune, c'est déjà un très bon avocat.*

or

> *Malgré son (très) jeune âge, c'est déjà un très bon avocat.*
>
> *En dépit de son (très) jeune âge, c'est déjà un très bon avocat.*
>
> *Même s'il est encore très jeune, c'est déjà un bon avocat.*

or even the [more than dubious](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/202/malgr%C3%A9-que-est-il-correct)

> **Malgré qu'il est très jeune, c'est déjà un bon avocat.*

I personally prefer the slightly more formal *bien que* than *même si* here, although both are correct.

The reason is *bien que* is always introducing a known fact in an opposition (like "**although**"), while *même **si*** (= even **if**) is normally introducing a hypothetical or irreal fact ([reference](http://research.jyu.fi/grfle/733.html) and [here too](https://hal.inria.fr/file/index/docid/306491/filename/Piot-W.pdf)). However, in our case the hypothesis is realized.

Here is a case of *même si* used to introduce a realized hypothesis, from the [TLFi *si* entry](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/si), I: D: 2. A)

> Et même si ce n'étaient là que des rêves, il ne faut pas jouer avec les rêves des hommes (Mauriac,Bâillon dén., 1945, p. 489).

In any case *même si encore très jeune* is not idiomatic, that should be *même s'il est encore très jeune*.

Unless used in a formal or literary context where the expression is sporadically found, *il est déjà un très bon avocat* has all other characteristics of an [anglicism](http://www.btb.termiumplus.gc.ca/tpv2guides/guides/clefsfp/index-fra.html?lang=fra&lettr=indx_catlog_a&page=9yNDoAZTLs8k.html), so I would advise to avoid it.

It would certainly be understood but is not what most native speakers would say. The closest idiomatic form would be *il est déjà très bon avocat* but this form is both rare and formal. *C'est déjà un très bon avocat* is much more common and can be used in both formal and informal writings and conversations. See also [this question](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/24439/il-est-when-it-means-il-y-a).

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/52995/discussion-on-answer-by-jlliagre-translation-of-although-still-very-young).

Answer (score 2):

> Même si encore très jeune, il est déjà un très bon avocat.

and

> Même si encore très jeune, c'est déjà un très bon avocat.

are grammatically correct, but the following IMHO sound more natural:

> Même s'il est encore très jeune, c'est déjà un très bon avocat.
>
> Bien qu'il soit encore très jeune, c'est déjà un très bon avocat.
>
> Bien que très jeune, c'est déjà un très bon avocat.

And maybe:

> Bien que très jeune, il est déjà bon avocat.

I would probably prefer "*il est*" rather than "*c'est*", because I would tend to use "*c'est*" for inanimate objects rather than people, but I think that both are completely acceptable in this case. I can't really tell whether one is in a better language register than the other, or whether one should be used only when speaking. I think they are really equivalent here. My only comment would be that "*Même si encore très jeune*" doesn't flow as well as "*Même s'il est encore très jeune*", in my opinion.

Comment: Isn't "il est un bon avocat" incorrect? I've read somewhere that we have to use "c'est un bon avocat". (For example, [here](http://www.frenchtoday.com/blog/cest-versus-il-elle-est).)

Comment: _In this case_, it looks ok to me. In some of the examples at our linked page, it wouldn't work: "_c'est mon mari_" cannot be replaced by "_il est mon mari_", indeed.

Comment: I couldn't tell in this case that one is definitely wrong. Maybe other native speakers will chime in with different opinions.

Comment: It seems like too nebulous an issue to give a solid answer on, but what I learned was that "ce" is okay for a person if you've used "il" first. One random example is this Notre-Dame de Paris song: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HfkQQxU8t5M ... "Il est beau comme le soleil / Est-ce un prince, un fils de roi ?"

Comment: @LukeSawczak - in this case, ""Il est beau comme le soleil / Est-**il** un prince, un fils de roi ?" would sound weird to me, meaning that "est-ce" seems like the only choice to me, from a usage point of view. Quoique...

Comment: @Frank Indeed. Now, the question is: could one have /begun/ with "Est-ce un prince ?" or was it necessary to use "il" first? (I learned that it was necessary, but it seems like one of the "rules" that's likely to chafe with usage.)

Comment: Yeah - I don't feel that having used "il" before is mandatory. It was not a rule I learnt. I could be true, but I doubt it.

Comment: I think the sentence "Il est/c'est un bon avocat" is interesting even alone, so I've created a new question [here](http://french.stackexchange.com/questions/24536/il-est-cest-un-bon-avocat).

Comment: *Il est déjà un très bon avocat* is an anglicism, *Il est déjà [très] bon avocat* is rare, but fine.

Comment: @jlliagre - comment décide-t'on ce qui est un anglicisme, et ce qui ne l'est pas? "_Il est déjà un très bon avocat_" ne me frappe pas immédiatement comme incorrect. Je suis juste curieux de savoir si on a une source pour les anglicismes.

Comment: http://www.btb.termiumplus.gc.ca/tpv2guides/guides/clefsfp/index-fra.html?lang=fra&lettr=indx_catlog_a&page=9yNDoAZTLs8k.html

Comment: Pour référence: ["il est un très bon"](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=il+est+un+tr%C3%A8s+bon&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=7&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cil%20est%20un%20tr%C3%A8s%20bon%3B%2Cc0) en Français.

Comment: "Il est un policier." se reconnaît facilement, mais c'est moins tranché pour "il est un très bon ...", à mon avis. De toute façon, "c'est" est plus heureux que "il est". Mais je ne rejetterais pas complètement "il est".